# Base Prisma Client type of multiple prisma clients

Tags: typescript, prisma

I have some generic test helper code that expects a prisma client

```
export async function truncateAllTables(prisma: any) {
  const tablenames = await prisma.$queryRaw<
    Array<{ tablename: string }>
  >`SELECT tablename FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname='public'`;

  const tables = tablenames
    .map(({ tablename }: any) => tablename)
    .filter((name: any) => name !== '_prisma_migrations')
    .map((name: any) => `"public"."${name}"`)
    .join(', ');

  console.warn(`truncating ${tables}`);

  try {
    await prisma.$executeRawUnsafe(`TRUNCATE TABLE ${tables} CASCADE;`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log({ error });
  }
}
```

however, as you can see i've had to type it as `prisma: any`.

My helper functions need to work for all prisma generated clients across a family of apps. Is there a way to type this?

e.g.

```
prisma: BasePrismaClient
```

or perhaps something like this (not very scalable), but for each app:

```
prisma: PrismaClient1 | PrismaClient2 | PrismaClient3
```

I was actually hoping there might be some generic base client type i could import from @prisma ?

Comment: Did you take a look at @prisma/client/src/runtime/getPrismaClient?

Comment: no i didn't but thanks for pointing it out. for me it's empy in @prisma since i have custom outputs for each client, but in .prisma-client1/runtime i could get that method, then i could create a type:
type Client = ReturnType<typeof getPrismaClient> extends new () => infer T
  ? T
  : never;
however, the methods in runtime aren't as generic, e.g.
$queryRaw(query: TemplateStringsArray | Sql, ...values: any[]): PrismaPromise_2<unknown>;
instead of
$queryRaw<T = unknown>(query: TemplateStringsArray | Prisma.Sql, ...values: any[]): Prisma.PrismaPromise<T>;
so it's not so useful